# How can I get the size of an array in Julia?

Tags: arrays, julia

I'm trying to run the following piece of code:

```
function inversePoly(A::Array{Int64,1}, B::Array{Int64,1})
    n = size(A)
    retVal = A[end] / B[end]
    i = 1
    while i != n
        retVal = (retVal + 1 / B[n - i]) * A[n - i]
        i += 1
    end
    return retVal
end

inversePoly(Array(3:4), Array(4:5))
```

However, Julia gives me the following error:

```
LoadError: MethodError: no method matching -(::Tuple{Int64}, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  -(!Matched::Complex{Bool}, ::Real) at complex.jl:298
  -(!Matched::Missing, ::Number) at missing.jl:97
  -(!Matched::Base.CoreLogging.LogLevel, ::Integer) at logging.jl:107
  ...
in expression starting at /home/francisco/Julia/abc.jl:12
inversePoly(::Array{Int64,1}, ::Array{Int64,1}) at abc.jl:6
top-level scope at none:0
```

The 6th line would be

```
retVal = (retVal + 1 / B[n - i]) * A[n - i]
```

This means that the statement

```
n = size(A)
```

Is saving a tuple in the variable n instead of an integer

How can I get an integer representing the number of elements in A?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is how you should use `size`:

```
julia> x = [1,2,3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> size(x)
(3,)

julia> size(x)[1]
3

julia> size(x, 1)
3
```

so either extract the first element from `size(x)` or directly specify which dimension you want to extract by passing `1` as a second argument.

In your case, as `A` is a `Vector` (it is single dimensional) you can also use `length`:

```
julia> length(x)
3
```

Which gives you an integer directly.

The difference between `length` and `size` is the following:

- `length` is defined for collections (not only arrays) and returns an integer which gives you the number of elements in the collection
- `size` returns a `Tuple` because in general it can be applied to multi-dimensional objects, in which case the tuple has as many elements as there are dimensions of the object (so in case of `Vector`, as in your question, it is 1-element tuple)

Comment: As a convenience for those used to `numpy` (which is possibly the reason for this question), you can think of Julia's `size` as analogous to `numpy`'s `shape`; and `length` analogous to both `numpy`'s `size` and Python's `len`.